# [EclipseLink-4002]: Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I'm trying to configure an EJB module with JPA-Hibernate, and i'm getting some kind of connection error when I try to deploy to GlassFish. I'm using MySQL, the modules are assigned to the MySQL data source and the db connection appears to fine.

I've attached the server log, the java code and hibernate.cfg.xml files.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance...

GlassFish Log

```
[2020-05-30T23:18:23.675+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [poolmgr.create_resource_error] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1590877103675] [levelValue: 900] [[
[2020-05-30T23:18:23.675+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [poolmgr.get_connection_failure] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1590877103675] [levelValue: 900] [[
[2020-05-30T23:18:23.677+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [WARNING] [jdbc.exc_get_conn] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1590877103677] [levelValue: 900] [[
  RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool DerbyPool. Exception : javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]

  RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ DerbyPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]

  RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).]]]

[2020-05-30T23:18:23.679+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/Users/marccooling/IdeaProjects/newglassfish/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/Test_ear/ejbmodule_jar/_NewPersistenceUnit.ejb] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1590877103679] [levelValue: 1000] [[

Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:769)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:138)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:147)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:142)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.AbstractDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDataSource.java:91)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.addResource(ConnectionPool.java:258)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResourceAndAddToPool(ConnectionPool.java:1487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResources(ConnectionPool.java:919)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.initPool(ConnectionPool.java:206)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.internalGetResource(ConnectionPool.java:490)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.getResource(ConnectionPool.java:357)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResourceFromPool(PoolManagerImpl.java:221)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl.getResource(PoolManagerImpl.java:147)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.getResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:336)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectionManagerImpl.internalGetConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:283)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:899)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createResource(ConnectionPool.java:1164)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.datastructure.RWLockDataStructure.addResource(RWLockDataStructure.java:74)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.ConnectionPool.createSingleResource(ConnectionPool.java:882)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: javax.resource.spi.ResourceAllocationException: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:105)
    at com.sun.enterprise.resource.allocator.LocalTxConnectorAllocator.createResource(LocalTxConnectorAllocator.java:63)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.BasicClientDataSource40.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.DSManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(DSManagedConnectionFactory.java:91)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: ERROR 08001: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetAgent.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.newAgent_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.initConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.BasicClientDataSource40.getConnectionX(Unknown Source)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.OpenSocketAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ... 81 more
]]

[2020-05-30T23:18:23.689+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1590877103689] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [Test_ear]]]

[2020-05-30T23:18:23.689+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1590877103689] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:468)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:107)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:86)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
]]

[2020-05-30T23:18:23.700+0100] [glassfish 5.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1590877103700] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while deploying the app [Test_ear] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.4.v20190115-ad5b7c6b2a): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1,527 with message Connection refused (Connection refused).
Error Code: 0]]
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jpa_module</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">***</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="javacode.CatalogItem" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

JPA Entity POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CATALOG_TABLE")
public class CatalogItem {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATALOG_TABLE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long itemID;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "MANUFACTURER")
    private String manufacturer;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "AVAILABLE_DATE")
    private Date availableDate;

    public CatalogItem() {

    }

    public CatalogItem(String name, String manufacturer, String description, Date availableDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.description = description;
        this.availableDate = availableDate;
    }

    public Long getItemID() {
        return itemID;
    }

    public void setItemID(Long itemID) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getAvailableDate() {
        return availableDate;
    }

    public void setAvailableDate(Date availableDate) {
        this.availableDate = availableDate;
    }

}
```

Bean1

```
@Singleton
@LocalBean
public class CatalogBean implements CatalogLocal {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private List<CatalogItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public CatalogBean() {
    }

    @Override
    public List<CatalogItem> getItems() {
        return this.entityManager.createQuery("select c from CatalogItem c",
                CatalogItem.class).getResultList();
    }

    @Override
    public void addItem(CatalogItem item) {
        this.entityManager.persist(item);
    }
}
```

Bean2

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class CatalogItemFormBean implements Serializable {

    @Inject

    private InventoryService inventoryService;

    private CatalogItem catalogItem = new CatalogItem();
    private List<CatalogItem> catalogItemList = new ArrayList<>();

    public String addItem() {

        this.catalogBean.addItem(new CatalogItem(this.catalogItem.getName(),
                this.catalogItem.getManufacturer(), this.catalogItem.getDescription(),
                this.catalogItem.getAvailableDate()));

        this.inventoryService.createItem(this.catalogItem.getItemID(), this.catalogItem.getName());

        return "list?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public void init() {
        this.catalogItemList = catalogBean.getItems();
    }

    public CatalogItem getCatalogItem() {
        return catalogItem;
    }

    public void setCatalogItem(CatalogItem catalogItem) {
        this.catalogItem = catalogItem;
    }

    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalogItemList() {
        return catalogItemList;
    }

    public void setCatalogItemList(List<CatalogItem> catalogItemList) {
        this.catalogItemList = catalogItemList;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you notice that your application is trying to connect to port `1527` (which might be apache derby for instance); where as in your datasource configuration you specified `mysql` with port `3306`. My guess is somehow your app is ignoring the hibernate configuration you provided.

Comment: hi @feanor07, thanks for the response. yes i did notice that. i've never setup derby, so i don't know where that's coming from. when i enable hibernate in ide, it creates the hibernate config file and a 'Main' class. the persistence.xml is empty, so i assume that's not being used. when i run the hibernate main class, the jpa-db connection is fine. it's when i deploy the app to GlassFish, i get the error. any further thoughts?